# how to get the current record id in flow

Tags: lightning, visual-workflow

I want to initiate a Flow from a button on a Custom Object.  How do I capture the ID of that Custom Object record and be able to use it in the Flow?
[image]

[image]

Comment: will you call it from a lightning page? You should create an input variable called recordId

Comment: @m Peixoto, see already created, can you please help me what I'm doing wrong here

Comment: if you would like to call from a button, could you create a Quick Action and call it?

Comment: https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=9063A000000id3jQAA

Comment: @m Peixoto thanks a lot ..!!!! working fine now